# Yammer deeplink from user authenticated with ADAL on Microsoft graph

Tags: deep-linking, microsoft-graph-api, adal, yammer

We have an Android Application using Adal authentication to access Microsoft Graph Api.
It's working quite fine and we retrieve authenticated user profile and collaborators profiles (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user).

Now, we are looking to create a deeplink from our application to Yammer application to display user details using the "Link to user" deeplink : https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android

The issue is : user id returned by Microsoft Graph can't be used to access User page in yammer app (ids are not the same between both platforms which seems quite normal)

So, how can I link a user from Microsoft Graph to a user in Yammer.

Thanks !